# Angularjs - form validation - simplfication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Newbie to angularjs/javascript

So I have lots of validation code, etc one set for username, email, password, name...etc. is there a way to make it cleaner or have a template and pass in the field name as the parameter?? etc.

```
        <div class="error item-input" ng-show=" joinForm.username.$dirty && joinForm.username.$invalid && isLoginBlurred">
            <small ng-show="joinForm.username.$error.required"> Your username is required.</small>
            <small ng-show="joinForm.username.$error.minlength"> Your username is required to be at least 5 characters</small>
            <small ng-show="joinForm.username.$error.maxlength"> Your username cannot be longer than 20 characters </small>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the ngForm directive of AngularJS.

```
<form name="signForm" ng-controller="FormController" novalidate>
<div ng-repeat="f in fields">
    <input type="text" name="{{f.name}}" ng-required="f.isRequired"/>
    <div ng-show="signForm[f.name].$dirty && signForm[f.name].$invalid">
        <span class="error" ng-show="signForm[f.name].$error.required">The field is required.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controller is

```
function FormController(scope) {
scope.fields = [
    { name: 'username', isRequired: true},
    { name: 'password', isRequired: true },
    { name: 'email', isRequired: false}
];
```